# How to see contents of exe in solaris

Tags: solaris, exe

I have an exe file(eg naming.exe) on my Solaris server.
I want to see the contents of the exe file.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question really and would probably be more appropriate for superuser.com, if others agree with me it will be migrated automatically, if not then nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

See the `strings` command which will extract readable text from a file. See [the article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_%28Unix%29) for more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Although Solaris and Unix in general doesn't care that much about suffixes, especially for executables.".exe" isn't a common file suffix there, it looks like a Windows thing to me.

Start by running `file naming.exe` to get an idea about what kind of file it is.

Answer (score 0):

Often data beyond simply strings is packed in too. (For example software installers sometimes have useful cross-platform data files embedded within executable files). On linux you can extract this using [cabextract](http://cabextract.org.uk/). I can't see any reason why porting this to Solaris would be hard if it isn't already working on Solaris.